# Google Sheet Remove Editors After First Edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to lock a cell in Google Sheet after the first entry in the cell and using below code and getting correct result. However,in this code a cell is locked after first entry but the owner and the editor can make further edits to the locked cell, however, I want to lock the cell for even the person who entered the data i.e. only the owner can make edit to the cell after it is locked`enter code here`.

```
function onEdit(e){
  let protection = e.range.protect();
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
  }
```

Any help on above will be appreciated.Below is the link of the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14qFZOKYUiQL4gKuLfdHPQwOgQ5LoY5P7KZyHN8ev-qY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your script is run by the simple trigger of OnEdit, I think that the reason for your issue might be due to this. In this case, please use the installable OnEdit trigger.

When you install the installable OnEdit trigger, please rename the function name. Because when `onEdit` function is installed as the installable trigger, when a cell is edited, 2 times of `onEdit` is run with the asynchronous process. Please be careful about this.

So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  let protection = e.range.protect();
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}

function installTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("installedOnEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
}
```

- In this script, when `installTrigger` is run, the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function `installedOnEdit`. By this, when a user who is not the owner of the Spreadsheet edits a cell, the cell is protected.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

### Added:

About your following new question,

> I want to lock the sheet for the editor also i.e. only owner can edit the sheet.

In this case, please modify the above script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  let protection = e.range.getSheet().protect();
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

- By the way, in this script, it supposes that you are the owner of the Spreadsheet, and you install the OnEdit trigger. So, if you want to install OnEdit trigger using `installTrigger`, please run the script by the owner. Please be careful about this.

Comment: The script shared by you gives the same result i.e. the user who made the edit can again edit the cell. I want to install protection post first entry in the cell so that only the owner of the sheet can make edit to that cell i.e. the cell should get protected for all except the owner.

Comment: @Edyphant Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `The script shared by you gives the same result i.e. the user who made the edit can again edit the cell.`, from `the owner and the editor can make further edits to the locked cell`, I had thought that you wanted to protect the cell from the user who is not the owner of the Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? By the way, even when the cell is protected, the owner can edit the cell. This is the current specification. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Edyphant When you want to protect the cell from the users who are not the owner of the Spreadsheet, when I tested my proposed method using the installable OnEdit trigger, I could confirm that it can be achieved. Also, when I used your script by the simple trigger of OnEdit, the protected cell can be edited by both the owner and the users who are not the owner. If this situation was not your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to lock the sheet for the editor also i.e. only owner can edit the sheet.

Comment: @Edyphant About your new question of `I want to lock the sheet for the editor also i.e. only owner can edit the sheet.`, I added one more modified script. Could you please confirm it? By the way, can I ask you whether your 1st question was resolved?

Comment: With your first script the range was getting locked and owner and editor were able to edit the locked range. Using your second script the sheet is not getting protected.

Comment: @Edyphant Thank you for replying. From `With your first script the range was getting locked and owner and editor were able to edit the locked range. Using your second script the sheet is not getting protected.`, I understood that your 1st question was resolved. About your 2nd quesiton, when I tested my proposed script, the sheet is protected. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue of your 2nd question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm testing this great idea and everything is going well on my end. It is absolutely useful! upvoted ...

Comment: @Mike Steelson Thank you for your support. I think that your comment will also help OP.

Comment: @ Tanakie.. thanks for the great solution its working perfect....Want to add one more thing. The current script does the desired work i.e. locks each cell individually after the editor, so is there any way by which the script identifies the last row in which there is value and locks the range till that row. Further, in this case when user again enters data in new row the earlier protection is removed and a new protection is applied till the last row having data.

Comment: @Edyphant Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 1st and 2nd questions were resolved.